# What is the formula for charging a capacitor with constant current?

Tags: capacitor, dc, constant-current

I read that the formula for calculating the time for a capacitor to charge with constant voltage is 5·τ = 5·(R·C) which is derived from the natural logarithm.

In another book I read that if you charged a capacitor with a constant current, the voltage would increase linear with time. Is this true, and if it is, what is the formula used for calculating this? Would a complete voltage charge be possible with a constant current?

Comment: To achieve a constant current through a capacitor implies that the voltage across the capacitor increases without limit. In reality, "without limit" is limited by the capacitor exploding. 5 tau is generally taken to be "good enough" at 99.3% charged.

Comment: A *real* constant current source such as a LM334 will "drop out" at its lower compliance limit and tail the charge current off as a result when the cap's fully charged up, provided the cap is rated well enough to not go bang first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Normally I would let you go and look as this is not a hard question to solve, but as I am feeling generous here is how we get there:

From fundamentals, we know that \$Q =CV\$

If we take the derivative with respect to time (remembering that \$I = \frac {Q} {T}\$) we yield

\$i = C\frac {dv} {dt}\$

Rearranging, we find that \$\frac {i} {C} = \frac {dv} {dt}\$

Therefore charging a capacitor from a constant current yields a linear ramp (up to the [compliance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69220/problem-on-output-compliance) of the current source).

I will leave finding the solution in terms of time versus some voltage to you.

Comment: charge time = C x V/I

Answer (score 1):

Here is the equation:

**charge time = C x V/I**

A good read: https://www.us.lambda.tdk.com/resources/blogs/202106.html